# Set print flush=True to default?

Tags: python, flush

I am aware that you can flush after a print statement by setting `flush=True` like so:

```
print("Hello World!", flush=True)
```

However, for cases where you are doing many prints, it is cumbersome to manually set each print to `flush=True`. Is there a way to set the default to `flush=True` for Python 3.x? I am thinking of something similar to the print options numpy gives using `numpy.set_printoptions`.

Comment: Just write your own function (and consider *why* you're explicitly flushing every single print - there's a reason it's not the default).

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica That's definitely valid. I am assuming then that there is no built-in support for altering the print options of print()?

Comment: @NotDuplicateSL Maybe it would be more reasonable to change the buffering of stdout through `stdbuf` ?

Comment: @user2357112 it is perfectly valid case and question. Consider that multithreading or calling external processes was added to the existing code in one file. And some methods are moved from and into that file from other files or even stackoverflow.

Comment: @atrelinski: I'm not sure how that's supposed to connect to the comment you're replying to, but if you're trying to say flushing on every call will make your prints threadsafe... no, it won't. You need actual synchronization for that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial):

```
from functools import partial
print_flushed = partial(print, flush=True)
print_flushed("Hello world!")
```

From the documentation:

> The partial() is used for partial function application which “freezes” some portion of a function’s arguments and/or keywords resulting in a new object with a simplified signature.

Answer (score 1):

One of the options is to create your own

```
def print_r(data):
  print(data, flush=True)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use something like this:

```
def decorator(func):
    printer = func
    def wrapped(*args):
        printer(*args, end=' *\n', flush=True)
    return wrapped

print = decorator(print)

for i in range(5):
    print(i)
```

```
0 *
1 *
2 *
3 *
4 *
```

Comment: That's really weird. Why the `end=' *\n'`? And why use a decorator at all?

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica The ```end``` was on purpose to show that we can have any value we like for the arguments. Also I didn't know that such ```partial``` exist in Python.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica I think it's just for the demonstration purposes as `flush=True`'s effect is not visible in the output.

Answer (score -1):

Using below code, makes all following `print()` calls be exectuted with `check=True` in the file.

```
import functools
print = functools.partial(print, flush=True) # all print()s will be called with "flush=True"
```

This solution overwrites the `print()` method by using [`partial`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.partial) functionality, which is described as:

> The partial() is used for partial function application which “freezes”
> some portion of a function’s arguments and/or keywords resulting in a
> new object with a simplified signature.